# Array printing out with large spaces?

Tags: java, arrays, file, text

Im trying to read from a text file a grid of dots and Xs, and add them to an array and print them out as one large grid. For some reason, it's printing sections of the Array in chunks, with large spaces in between those chunks in the console. If i use a toString it prints the memory location, so I'm not sure whats going on here...

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Created a scanner
        System.out.println("Enter the file name you would like to use");
        File file = new File(input.nextLine()); // Takes file name to find file
        Scanner inputFromFile = new Scanner(file);
        String line = inputFromFile.nextLine();
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file); // reads file
        int r;
        while ((r = fileInput.read()) != -1) { // goes through each character in
                                                // file, char by char
            char c = (char) r;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
                for (int y = 0; y <= 3; y++) {
                    GameOfLife.grid[i][y] = c;
                    for (int j = 0; j < GameOfLife.grid.length; j++)
                        System.out.println(GameOfLife.grid[j]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

GameOfLife:

```
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class GameOfLife {

static final int m = 25; // number of rows
static final int n = 75; // number of columns 
static char[][] grid = new char [m][n]; // Creates an empty (no dots or X's)grid of rows and columns. 


}
```

Comment: Where is code for GameOfLife

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Adding it now

Comment: use `system.out.print` rather than `system.out.println`

Comment: That prints everything on one line, but i was hoping for a grid formation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing the content of the array outside of the while loop. What you are doing is printing all of the contents of your grid after each character has been added to it

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the grid after every character.

You need something like:

```
    // Walk the whole grid.
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <= 3; y++) {
            // Read a character from the file.
            int r = fileInput.read();
            if (r != -1) {
                GameOfLife.grid[i][y] = (char) r;
            } else {
                // End of file before grid filled!!! TODO! Deal with this.
            }
        }
    }
    // Print out the results.
    for (int j = 0; j < GameOfLife.grid.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(GameOfLife.grid[j]);
    }
```